# How to meaningfully describe the practical effectiveness of one large bomb versus a series of many small bombs, all else constant?

Tags: potential-energy, explosions

**Background:**

Given two sets of conventional bombs (constituted of fuel which explodes by way of chemical decomposition reaction) :

*Set 1* - One shell of a given volume encasing a given amount of fuel. (1 30cm^3 shell w/ 3 kg TNT)

*Scenario 1*: Set 1 is detonated at a location.

*Set 2* - Many shells of equal volumes encasing equal amounts of fuel, both cumulatively equating to the respective quantities from Set 1. (3 10cm^3 shells, w/ 1 kg TNT each)

*Scenario 2*: Each member of Set 2 is detonated at identical locations, in between time intervals long enough so that no detonation interacts with another.

Begin with this naive assumption: Fuel/Volume in Set 1 = Fuel/Volume in Set 2; therefore, the practical effectiveness of detonating Set 1 = the practical effectiveness of detonating Set 2. Clearly this overlooks an important inequality between the two scenarios, namely the quantity of time in which the detonations occur.

This line of thought ultimately leads to an investigation towards a complete description of the relationship between scenario 1 and 2.

**My description:**

My general description will attempt to start from the term *Practical effectiveness* and move backwards until reaching the attributes of Set 1 and Set 2, with the hope to then be in a position to meaningfully compare Set 1 and Set 2.

*Practical effectiveness* : I insist on starting with this ambiguous term in order to authentically represent what I am in fact curious to understand.  I'll resolve the term like so: *"the capacity to cause damage"* -> *"strength of and area covered by overpressure from the resultant blast wave"* (note we're ignoring heat, in itself; shock waves; blast wind; fragmentation, etc.) -> [*"Explosive Power"*](http://www.globalspec.com/reference/55654/203279/explosive-power-and-power-index) - > **This is where things get a bit dubious for me (and remember, we're holding constant other factors like constituent chemicals, shell wall strength, etc.)** *"Volume of gas and heat of explosion"* -> *"Amount of fuel per shell volume per detonation time lapse"*

**Question:**

I'm fairly confident in my description up until *"Explosive Power"*.

Here are the factors that I believe are pertinent in accurately and meaningfully continuing the description after *"Explosive Power"* :

Chemical potential energy of bombs, power of explosions, amount of fuel per shell per detonation time lapse, volume of gas and heat produced in shell.

I'm having trouble connecting these factors, however.

I understand that power is work/time, so the same amount of work done in less time indicates greater power; however, I am having trouble intuitively moving from equal potential chemical energy in Set 1 and Set 2 **(is this indeed the case?)**, to unequal overpressure (a force).

Assuming my terms are adequate, please help to reorganize my description in a more meaningful, intuitively satisfying way, or simply critique my description.  I am not asking so much to fill a technical gap, but do some pedagogical enhancements to clear up a matter for which a small perspective shift might do wonders.

Comment: Define "more power"

Comment: @KyleKanos  It means use a Binford tool! (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Improvement_(TV_series))

Comment: @KyleKanos In this case by power I mean, at a conceptual level, the potential to cause damage.  Though I'd also be interested in an answer pertaining strictly to the physical definition of power.

Comment: Then you need to define "potential to cause damage."

Comment: @KyleKanos Perhaps I can't in terms especially meaningful to the physics community (of which I'm admittedly not a part); but, if you'll accept empirical rather than theoretical terms: given two explosions in the same physical environment, the one with the greater potential power will have a greater physical effect on that environment...physical effect perhaps being more particles moved.

Comment: The comments are starting to clear up the confusion here, but please make an edit to your post clarifying what you're asking (based on the comments, probably). Voting to close until that's done, but will happily re-open once that happens.

Comment: I'm afraid even the most recent definition is not much use. It really matters whether you are trying to, say, open a bank vault, rapidly remove some unwanted sandstone from a road-cut, or (alas) kill a bunch of people in a urban environment. Different tools for different jobs.

Comment: All I can do is repeat what I said before *"capacity to cause damage"* is a context dependent idea. Some purposes simply demand high pressure, while others are better handled by dispersing the energy over a wider volume. Say what you care to *do* and the explosives guys will have an answer.

Comment: @dmckee You did not read the question. I specified my terms to compare the starting chemical potential energy in a container(s) of a certain volume to the strength and area covered by the resultant overpressure. That's what I care to _be able_ to do - create great overpressure over a great area. If those terms aren't meaningful, please offer some that are.

Comment: I read it twice, followed the links and thought about them. The problem is that the answer depends on the properties of [whatever you are trying to blow up] in a non-linear way.

Comment: @dmckee I appreciate that you haven't completely abandoned the question; whether it ever gets taken off hold/closed, my curiosity remains. Am I wrong in interpreting the "Explosive Power Index" referenced in my question not to consider what you are trying to blow up?  How to reconcile this with your insistence that explosive power depends on what you are blowing up?

Comment: What depends on what you are trying to blow up is *how you deploy your explosive* which seems to be exactly what you are asking about. As far as I can tell that explosive power metric that you found allows you to convert between quantities of different explosives (i.e if I needed four ounces of TNT, how much RDX do I use instead?).

Comment: @dmckee You're exactly right. I suppose the fundamental flaw in my expectations with this question is that I want to determine a purely theoretical "potential power," based on a purely theoretical "potential energy."  The problem is that while potential energy is by definition ~purely theoretical, power is by definition not purely theoretical, in that it requires a concrete _time_ and a concrete _object_ on which work is to be performed. Agreed?

Comment: @dmckee I take back what I said about the necessity for a concrete _object_. If work is force*displacement, the work that potential energy can perform can be determined in pure theory, i.e. absent an _object_. The flaw with my question was with the need for a concrete time, nothing more, I believe.

Answer (score 5):

I think your question is a bit too ambiguous to answer properly, but here is one way to consider the situation.

Suppose you've got a nail, and you know it takes 10 Newtons (a made-up value) to make it put a dent in a board.  If you hit the nail with a hammer, with an impulse force which peaks at 1 Newton,  hitting ten times in succession will do nothing.

The point is:  many MANY physical behaviors are strongly nonlinear, so one large impulse force can succeed where hundreds of small impulses will have no effect.

Comment: I suppose my question, then, is: In virtue of what is it the case that physical effects like the one in question have a non-linear relationship to their causes?

Answer (score 0):

That's essentially what a Time On Target attack is all about. There are a couple of ways to use TOT:

- "George, you take out this target, John, you take out that target, you over there take out that third target..., and I'll take out this *N*<sup>th</sup> target, with our bombs all within 3 seconds of one another."
  The idea is to take out the officers, command post, comm equipment, barracks, and munitions, all at once. This can be extremely devastating to the enemy.
- "George, you aim at this target with time of arrival set to within 3 seconds of 0600; John, you do the same; you over, you do the same thing, too; ..., and I'll do the exactly the same thing as well."
  This worked nicely during World War II, but that was because timing and accuracy weren't particularly high.

There's a basic problem with the second approach, which is what you are asking about. If everyone's bombs arrive within (for example) a few tens of feet of the target and a few thousands of a second apart, the first bomb to explode will take out part of the target -- and also all of the other incoming bombs.

If the bombs are spread more widely over space and time, the combined effects are less than additive. A single big bomb is beyond additive. A single 10<sup>4</sup> kiloton bomb will do a great deal more damage than 10,000 small bombs.

Comment: My question is why are the combined effects less than additive with greater space and time spread and vice versa?

Comment: If you jump up and down on your bed 50 times it will survive the onslaught. Your bed will collapse if you drop an elephant that weighs 50 times what you do just once on your bed.

Comment: Thanks - I fully appreciate and intuit the concept; I'm searching for a theoretical basis therefor. I'll edit my question to reflect so.

Comment: Conversely, many small bombs are generally ineffective against hardened targets for which you want either a designed penetrator or a really high pressure device. Which is why the question is still too much of a mess to be answered.